# Get the count of the same options from multiple dropdowns in a table

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, datatable

in this table I need to get the total count of options having green value selected or red or yellow from the dropdown bar and show it on the green yellow re input boxes.

Html Code:

```html
<td>
  <select class="form-control col-md-6 " type="text" id="Zone" name="Zone">
    {% for z in Zone %}
      <option value="{{ z.ZoneName }}">{{ z.ZoneName }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</td>
```

Script code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#calculatebtn").on('click', function () {
        Calculate();
    });
});

function Calculate() {
    // var green = $("tbody tr:visible td:select:nth-child(5):contains('Green')").length;
    var tasks = $('#myTable tr').length - 1;
    var green = parseInt($("#Green").val() * 20);
    // console.log(green)
    var yellow = parseInt($("#Yellow").val() * 10);
    // console.log(yellow)
    var red = parseInt($("#Red").val() * 5);
    // console.log(red)
    var help = parseInt($("#Help").val() * 10);
    // console.log(help)
    var notdone = parseInt($("#NotDone").val() * 20);
    // console.log(notdone)
    var bonus = $('input:checkbox:checked').length - 4;
    // var bonus=parseInt($("#Bonus").val() * 20);
    // console.log(bonus)
    var result = green + yellow + red;
    // console.log(result)
    var total = (green + yellow + red + bonus) - (help + notdone);
    // console.log(total)
    var warpercent = (result / 100) * tasks;
    document.getElementById("Green").value = green
    document.getElementById("Total").value = total
    document.getElementById("Bonus").value = bonus
    document.getElementById("Score").value = result
    document.getElementById("Total").value = total
    document.getElementById("Game").value = game
}
```

[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKVC2.png)

Comment: So do you want a solution for the client (`javascript`, `jquery`) or the server (`php`, `django`)? And why is this tagged with `datatable`?

Comment: And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own ([How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users))?

Comment: I have used datatables for every table display so i was just wondering if there is an inbuilt term to get the count of the dropdowns.

Comment: Just added the script code

Comment: i'm loooking for a solution on clientside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your selectbox . Inside this depending on the value  add `1` to your variable and then add final result inside relevant box using `.val()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calculatebtn").on('click', function() {
    Calculate();
  });


function Calculate() {
  var green = 0;
  var yellow = 0;
  var red = 0;
  //loop through slect
  $("select[name=Zone]").each(function() {
  //check select value
    if ($(this).val() == "Green") {
      green = green + 1
    } else if ($(this).val() == "Yellow") {
      yellow = yellow + 1
    } else {
      red = red + 1
    }

  })

//add total..
  $("#Green").val(green)
  $("#Red").val(red)
  $("#Yellow").val(yellow)
  $("#Total").val(green + red + yellow)


}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control col-md-6 " type="text" name="Zone">
        <option value="Green">Green</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control col-md-6 " type="text" name="Zone">
        <option value="Green">Green</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control col-md-6 " type="text" id="Zone" name="Zone">
        <option value="Green">Green</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control col-md-6 " type="text" id="Zone" name="Zone">
        <option value="Green">Green</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control col-md-6 " type="text" name="Zone">
        <option value="Green">Green</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="calculatebtn">Calculate</button>
<br>Green
<input type="text" id="Green"><br> Yellow
<input type="text" id="Yellow"> <br> Red : <input type="text" id="Red"> <br> Total :<input type="text" id="Total">
```